# Shall we create two urls with in the same zone using alternate access mapping?

Tags: sharepoint, alternate-access-mappings

We can create different urls for the site by using the alternate access mapping for different zones which are available. But I am trying to create two urls with in the same zone which is used for internal and external purpose. But I am unable to find the way to create. Is it possible to create? If so, can any one please explain?

Comment: Stackoverflow is about programming related questions. Please refer to sharepoint.stackexchange.com for other questions.

Answer (score 1):

As it was sad before:

> You can only have one URL per Zone...

For two different URL you can use [host site header collections](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424952%28v=office.14%29.aspx) instead.

This will give you a possibility to create different site collections with appropriate URL for each of them. Be aware that you cannot use no more "AAM" if you go to host header collections solution!

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can assign different URLs for one mapping. You can only have one URL per Zone. See this example:

[image]

My default URL for the access mapping collection "SharePoint Portal" (a web application) is `http://sp.dev` the custom URL is `http://blabla.com`. You can edit these via using "Edit public URLs" in central administration.

Comment: Thanks @moontear. Yeah this thing i know. I am asking that can't we add two urls for a single zone?